# Content-Length Header in Http 2 for POST/PUT request with empty body required?

Tags: http2, http-content-length

I am receiving a 411 length required error when sending HTTP2 POST requests without a body to an Azure API Management (but this is not a question about Azure).
my request is:

```
curl --location --request POST "..." --header "Content-Type: application/json"  --verbose --http2
```

I'm getting the following logs from curl:

```
 ...
 Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
 ...
 * Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
 < HTTP/2 411
 < content-type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
 ...
 < content-length: 344
 < 
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 
 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
 <BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
 <hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
```

I thought this was not necessary for HTTP2, and tried reading what the HTTP2 RFC says about it, but found [it](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540.html#section-8.1.2.6) confusing:

> A request or response that includes a payload body can include a
> content-length header field.

But what about requests that don't have a body?

Who is correct here, the client who does not send the header, or the server who does not accept the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTTP/1.1 `POST` requests, client SHOULD send the `Content-Length` header, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.2.

For HTTP/2, the `Content-Length` header is not mandated (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.6), since the protocol has the `endStream` flag to signal the end of the content.

However, server-side applications are typically written against a higher level HTTP semantic: they don't care whether the request came as HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2, they just care if it was a POST with some header and some content that they want to process.
See [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html) for the definition of the high level HTTP semantic.

Given that HTTP/1.1 lasted for 20+ years and HTTP/2 is relatively new, server-side applications may still *assume* HTTP/1.1 and complain if some header that is present in HTTP/1.1 is missing because the request came as HTTP/2.

For example, HTTP/2 requests do not have the `Host` header anymore (instead, they have an `:authority` pseudo-header); however, HTTP/2 specifies that when translating HTTP/2 to HTTP/1.1 the `Host` header must be synthetically generated (see [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.3)).

The same may happen to the `Content-Length` header: an old server-side application that assumes HTTP/1.1 expects the `Content-Length` header to be there, but when the request comes as HTTP/2 it may not have it because for HTTP/2 it is not strictly necessary.
Here, "server-side application" may mean a reverse-proxy feature provided by a front-end server, or some Azure translation layer, or the final application reached by the request.

The most portable solution with `curl` would be for you to add `Content-Length: 0`, or to specify an empty body with `-d ''` (so that `curl` adds the `Content-Length: 0` header).